# Inserting unique code macros in Google Tag Manager (GTM) datalayer

Tags: macros, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I'm working on implementing datalayers for Google Tag Manager e-commerce tracking in a system that has it's own internal macros for inserting variables onto pages.

For example, in the system, inserting this...

```
<@orderNumber></@orderNumber>
```

..onto a confirmation page will display the customer order number when the html page is rendered in the browser.

With that in mind, I've successfully created and tested a datalayer like this:

```
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
dataLayer.push({
   'transactionId': '<@orderNumber></@orderNumber>',
   'transactionTotal': <@orderTotal></@orderTotal>,
   'transactionProducts': [{
       'sku': '<@orderCode></@orderCode>',
       'name': '<@productName/>',
       'price': <@orderTotal></@orderTotal>,
       'quantity': 1
   }]
});
</script>
```

It works perfectly.

However, I now need to try rolling it out to all of our confirmation pages. There are thousands of these, so doing it manually isn't an option.

So I thought I could insert the datalayer using GTM...

However, these customer macros are immediately blocked as invalid Javascript by GTM (which is correct, I guess, as they aren't valid).

I feel like I've hit a brick wall with this, but maybe I'm just too close to the woods to see the trees, as they say (and I'm not that familiar with GTM anyway, so am learning as I go really). I know nobody will have come across this specific issue before, as these macros are unique to the system I'm working on, but has anyone encountered a similar problem before, and could point me in the right direction?

Am I doomed to manually inserting this on thousands of pages? :)

Comment: Somehow there is information missing. Usually macros like this are substituted via some server-side process, which GTM would not support (this is injected javascript after all, so it never sees your server). Also thousands of confirmation pages sounds strange, one would expect that there is some kind of master template that supplies shared functionality. I guess we would need to learn a little more about your system to be able to help you.

Comment: Also one does insert manually lines into thousands of text files, this is what command line tools like i.e. sed are for (also some IDEs offer functions to search and replace in many files).

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified that: These macros ARE substituted by the server when the page loads... meaning they are available to the datalayer before it gets pushed to GA. (So when you view the confirmation page in your browser, you can see the datalayer populated with the correct values for that particular order.)

Also, you'd think there would be some kind of shared template, but there isn't. It's an OLD system (really old... circa 2006, I think) that I don't think anyone ever thought would grow as large as it has, or that it would still be in use today. But it is... :-)

Comment: (Also, I know there are ways to search-and-replace within files, but the pages in this system aren't accessible in that way (again, because of it's great age, probably). You HAVE to manually open each individual page in order to edit them. (In fact, the only reason Tag Manager is present is because someone had an intern manually go through them all and add it!)

Comment: My condolences, this sounds really messed up. In a vaguely similar situation I once proposed the "dataLayer as a service", i.e. an API endpoint that returns a datalayer depending on the calling url which GTM would load via an Ajax call in a custom HTML tag. I meant that as a joke, but based on your description it would be the only way to avoid a lot of manual intervention.

Comment: Haha... thanks for the condolences. It really is messed up! :-)